# How can I make random forest have multiple valid outcomes?

Tags: machine-learning, multiple-regression, random-forest

I am new in machine learning I will describe my problem with similar approach.

I want to make a random forest with multiple but diffrent outcomes.

My example is I want the decision tree or random forest to decide which clothes should i wear in some event(example custome party or bussniess meeting...) but I need it to decide which hat is appropriate, which t-shirt is appropriate, shoes...

All have the same root that is me wearing them and the event but with diffrent clothes body parts.

For example in bussniss meeting  in my upper half I will wear a suit with tie or butterfly tie and blue texido or black texido
I mean in the same tree there will possible multiple outcomes.

I hope what I mean is clear.

Comment: Why does it have to be a single random forest for all of these clothing items instead of a random forest for hats, another random forest for shirts, and another random forest for pants?

Comment: Do you mean to say you'd like to classify the most likely clothing item based on variables such as event and body part the clothing covers?

Comment: Yes in that example the items can be independent of each other,  let's say I have customer who will write their own car specification with details for example the car must be medium sized with red color,  have wide back, turbo engine... With many diffrent specifications, and currently I have multiple cars that satisfy the customer needs and I need a random firest for it. I mean I want from natural language processing get the key words then with the decision tree I get the best fit or multiple fit.

Comment: Okay, well that's a very interesting problem. But it seems to me that your problem is very broadly stated here. That's normally okay by me, but it seems like you may be missing some pre-requisite ML/DL knowledge it would take to implement such a recommender system.  Perhaps you would be better served by checking out some online courses that cover ML/DL concepts, and then bring your specific questions?

Comment: Yes thank you,  I think I am trying to  make reverse decision tree, I think there is no need to do that, it can be achieved by maybe simple database filters after all. My project need me to do machine learning but I am not really convenced for the need of that.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to say you'd like to classify the most likely clothing item based on variables such as event and body part the clothing covers, it seems fairly trivial to condition a model off of those two variables such that your input is some tuple `x = (event_type, body_part)` and the output is `y = clothing_item`. For a full output, say hat, shirt and pants for a costume party, you'd need three inputs:

- `x = (party, head)`
- `x = (party, torso)`
- `x = (party, legs)`

And hopefully, your random forest would give you three corresponding outputs based on your training data. Or, you could build a model that outputs a probability distribution based on each input, giving you some likely candidates to choose from.